# How to deal with "number stored as text" in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

The connection is a table in Oracle DB, and some number columns have strings in them. As a result, Excel load the numbers as "numbers stored as text".

[image].

The most straight-forward way is to choose the region with the error, and format cells. But, if we format the whole column, errors remained. Is there a way to deal with this? Maybe even without VBA?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is to use "Text to Columns". Use the default settings of the "Convert Text to Columns Wizard" and you will find the columns "cleaned". Why is that?

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns), return value of the `range.TextToColumns` is `Variant`. Loosel translated, each cell in the range is dynamically-typed.

```
range("A:A").TextToColumns  ' text to columns: col A
range("A:A").NumberFormat = "General"  ' formatting
```